# Python kivy code from book Kivy Blueprints

Tags: python, function, parameters, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to follow the book "Kivy Blueprints" from Mark Vasilkov. On page 21 he introduces a function that updates the text of a label.

There are two files inside the project folder (see code below). Inside the class ClockApp the function `update_time(self, nap)` is defined. I am using Intellij Idea Community with the python plugin and the integrated development environment (IDE) tells me that `nap` is an unused parameter. If I remove `nap` as parameter I get an error `update_time() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. How can I get rid of this dummy parameter?

```
# Source: Chapter 1 of Kivy Blueprints
# File: main.py
from time import strftime

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex


Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex("#101216")
# from kivy.core.text import LabelBase


class ClockApp(App):

    def update_time(self, nap):

        self.root.ids.time.text = strftime("[b]%H[/b]:%M:%S")

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_time, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ClockApp().run()
```

There is also an additional clock.kv file

```
# File: clock.kv
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        id: time
        text: "[b]00[/b]:00:00"
        font_name: "Roboto"
        font_size: 60
        markup: True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the binding always passes additional information, for example in this case it sends us the exact time period in which the function was called. If you do not want to use it you can use a lambda method:

```
class ClockApp(App):
    def update_time(self):
        self.root.ids.time.text = strftime("[b]%H[/b]:%M:%S")

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda *args: self.update_time(), 1)
```

if you only want to silence the warning: "unused parameter" you could use the `_`:

```
class ClockApp(App):
    def update_time(self, _):
        self.root.ids.time.text = strftime("[b]%H[/b]:%M:%S")

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_time, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you prefer using the additional parameter or the lambda method? I mean which would you prefer because it is a better style?

Comment: @MrYouMath see my additional answer, It depends on the opinion of each one

Comment: Thank you for your time. The underscore seems to be the less intrusive solution to me. Even if that is not perfect I will stick to that convention.